# WELD-001300 when trying to lookup BeanManager by JNDI

Tags: jetty, cdi, weld

I configured Jetty 9.2.5 + Weld 2.2.7 (currently the latest versions) as described by the [Weld documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html).

Everything works fine, except the lookup of the BeanManager by JNDI. Lookup of other JNDI entries just work as expected. I got the error (note this is not a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`)

```
javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
```

The code I use:

```
BeanManager beanManager = null;
try {
    final Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    try {
        // JNDI name defined by spec
        beanManager = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NameNotFoundException nf1) {
        try {
            // JNDI name used by Tomcat and Jetty
            beanManager = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
        } catch (NameNotFoundException nf2) {
        }
    }
} catch (NamingException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
return beanManager;
```

Complete test code can be found at https://github.com/rmuller/java8-examples/tree/master/jetty-maven-cdi

Comment: You don't have an `env-entry` for `BeanManager`

Comment: Yes, I have: https://github.com/rmuller/java8-examples/blob/master/jetty-maven-cdi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-overwrite-jetty.xml (copied from the Weld documentation page)

Comment: I don't see it here.. https://github.com/rmuller/java8-examples/blob/master/jetty-maven-cdi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L21

Comment: It is in the `web-overwrite-jetty.xml` (as stated in the documentation). If I move it to `web.xml` same problem still there. However note that I use `resource-env-ref` and not `env-entry` which cannot be used for a Reference type afaik. So now I am lost :)

Comment: I reviewed all code carefully again and made some modifications, so check the updated repo for details. Should be okay now, but reported problem still exists.

Comment: I have the save problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866682/jetty9-spring4-2-hibernate5-omnifaces2-2-cant-work-cdi-beanmanager-instance/34893097#34893097

Answer (score 0):

This has similar symptoms to a problem I ran into with Tomcat 7/8 and Weld 2.2.6. In my case, it was related to a bug in WELD, which was fixed in 2.2.7. So it shouldn't have been affecting the original poster's setup.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1776

Comment: Thanks, but i do not think this bug is related. My problem still exists with Weld version 2.2.9 and 3 (alpha1). Currently i do not use jdni lookup anymore (using `CDI.current().getBeanManager()`)