# jetty9,spring4.2,hibernate5,omnifaces2.2,can't work - "CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI."

Tags: jetty, cdi, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

The application can't startup correctory,the root cause is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:106)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<clinit>(BeanManager.java:49)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:69)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:415)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:248)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:488)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:287)
    ...
```

but If I use omnifaces 1.10,that's no problem,and I have try this way:
[Deploying a war to Jetty with CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483186/deploying-a-war-to-jetty-with-cdi)
but exception also,but "Unable to locate BeanManager"

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hn.aisino</groupId>
  <artifactId>taxno_alter</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>taxno_alter Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>




  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
      <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
      <version>2.0b5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8-02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8-02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
      <artifactId>bluesky</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1-b04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1-b04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
          <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>




  <build>
    <finalName>taxno_alter</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.3.v20150827</version>
        <configuration>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <contextXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


    <!-- The master configuration file for this Spring web application -->

    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>personal_credit</name>
        <others/>
    </absolute-ordering>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
        </param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>60000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Loads the Spring web application context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.domain.service.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>javaxServletHttpWrapper</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.interfaces.web.servlet.JavaxServletHttpWrapFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>javaxServletHttpWrapper</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>tmpFolderPermissionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.interfaces.web.servlet.TmpFolderPermissionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>tmpFolderPermissionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/tmp/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>picFolderPermissionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.interfaces.web.servlet.PicFolderPermissionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>picFolderPermissionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pic/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <!-- Override init parameter to avoid nasty -->
        <!-- file locking issue on windows.         -->
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xlt</extension>
        <mime-type>excel/template</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>start.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.access.UnauthorizedException</exception-type>
        <location>/default.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.hn.aisino.taxno_alter.access.NotLoggedInException</exception-type>
        <location>/permission/login.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/default.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

web-fragment.xml

```
<web-fragment xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
              version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <name>personal_credit</name>
    <distributable />
    <ordering>
        <before>
            <others />
        </before>
    </ordering>
</web-fragment>
```

jetty-context.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>

</Configure>
```

and also have other config file like beans.xml and spring config xml files that if need, i'll post laterly.

I have work on this problem for servel days but make no progress,so anyone's help is very appreciate!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jetty, but exception clearly tells `BeanManager` isn't available in JNDI. The accepted answer of the question you found tells how to register it in jetty-env.xml. I'm not seeing that back in your question.

Comment: I have tried the jetty-env.xml, but also can't work.  I am planning to use tomcat or jboss-as. by the way, what application server you are prefered?

Comment: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Compatibility-Matrix I will perhaps investigate/test later with Jetty+CDI.

Comment: ok, Thank you.  Maybe I use some wrong dependency or some wrong config

Answer (score 1):

Based on the contents you posted, it seems like you're not binding your bean manager to JNDI in Jetty.  I would recommend making sure you're on all of the latest JARs (e.g. weld 2.3.2 instead of 2.2.6, hibernate 5.0.7, etc) as well to make sure you're on the most supported of libraries.

Instructions to bind the bean manager to JNDI can be found in the weld docs here: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty

In addition to `jetty-env.xml`, please make sure you add the reference in `web.xml`

Comment: I have already test this,but the new Excption is: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace (update your question).

Answer (score 0):

because the text length is over 30000,so i can't edit the question,instead of post an answer:

I add the jetty-env.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="BeanManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx"/>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg/>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

and add the blew content to the end of web.xml

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

</web-app>
```

and upgrade the dependency to the newest version in maven centrel repo.
now the full stacktrace is:

```
严重: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:69)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:405)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:251)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:99)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<clinit>(BeanManager.java:49)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
    at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:95)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:95)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ManagerObjectFactory.java:62)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:533)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:106)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:90)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: It seems that the jetty-maven-plugin haven't read the jetty-env.xml when I use "men jetty:run" to start the jetty

Comment: and I found that use weld-servlet 2.1.x and jetty-maven-plugin 9.0.x.... seems to work