# Exception using weld CDI with Jetty: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE

Tags: jetty, cdi, maven-jetty-plugin, weld

I am trying to configure Jetty with JSF and Weld CDI. After following [this](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty) manual, I stumble upon the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE => []
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.RegistrySingletonProvider$RegistrySingleton.get(RegistrySingletonProvider.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.SimpleCDI.<init>(SimpleCDI.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.WeldProvider$EnvironmentCDI.<init>(WeldProvider.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.WeldProvider.getCDI(WeldProvider.java:61)
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.api.helpers.ForwardingServletListener.contextInitialized(ForwardingServletListener.java:34)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    ... 50 more
```

Does someone see what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you mind the `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` file?

Comment: This is my WEB-INF/beans.xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>

Comment: Problem suggests BeanManager can't be found. Which Jetty version is it? 9.2.4+ allows an easier way of configuring: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html

Comment: See my version numbers and other configuration in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/529250b4387c4b6103aa . I try to be on the newest version.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling, did you resolve your problem?

Comment: No I transitioned from a servlet container (Jetty) to a J2EE server (Wildfly)

Answer (score 6):

This error appears if you forget the **beans.xml** file or, as in my case, you have put it in the wrong place. Your beans.xml can have only the root element but must exist.

For a **Maven** project remember that:

- `context.xml` shoud stay in `src/main/webapp/META-INF/`
- `beans.xml` should stay in `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

I had this problem when I moved an application developed using Glassfish (that doesn't need these files) to Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using both `weld-servlet` and `weld-servlet-core` in your pom.  This is causing duplicate class entries as weld-servlet is an aggregate of weld-servlet-core.  Removing the weld-servlet-core dependency fixed the singleton not set error.

Now, when I did that, I received errors about JSF but that may be other configuration issues.

Comment: I got to this point because I needed the org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler for Bootsfaces, so I started to add Omnifaces. Then it turned out I needed CDI, so I added weld. Right now I try to find matching versions for weld, jsf, etc.etc. so I can get the configuration to work in my test runner, the jetty-maven-plugin. I am actually starting to believe that such a configuration does simply not exist, as I keep running into other exceptions. Could you perhaps have a look at the "other configration issues"?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666681/weld-001300-when-trying-to-lookup-beanmanager-by-jndi and https://github.com/skaterkamp/streichelzoo-faces/blob/master/streichelzoo-site-webapp/pom.xml#L174